# What does a C++ compiler do with this initializer list?

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

When using an initializer list such as this:

```
for (int i : {3, 1, 6, 4})
{
    std::cout << "i=" << i << std::endl;
}
```

The ouput is in the same order, 3, 1, 6, and finally 4.  So I know the compiler must be using something similar to `std::vector<int>` and not `std::set<int>`.

Is this guaranteed?  Where can I find the docs that explain how the compiler must interpret `{3, 1, 6, 4}`.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list

Comment: In the current standard. Here is the [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/links) to downloadable drafts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your [range based loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) is using the [braced-init-list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) as a range expression which constructs a temporary object of type [std::initializer_list<int>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list). The order is guaranteed because the 8.5.4.5. paragraph of the [n4140 draft / standard](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n4140.pdf?raw=true) states (emphasis mine):

> An object of type std::initializer_list<E> is constructed from an
>   initializer list **as if** the implementation allocated a temporary
>   **array of N elements** of type const E, where N is the number of
>   elements in the initializer list.

Answer (score 9):

You are creating an instance of `std::initializer_list<int>`. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list for details.

From that page:

> An object of type `std::initializer_list<T>` is a lightweight proxy object that provides access to an array of objects of type `const T`.

The output order is guaranteed. However, that's not because the compiler creates a `std::vector<int>`. It is guaranteed because there is an array of `int`s underneath the `initializer_list`.

Comment: Side question: since the constructor of `std::initializer_list` takes a `const T*`, how does the compiler manage the lifetime of the underlying `T[]` ? Is there code somewhere that explicits that were're not taking the address of a temporary, or is it handled directly by the compiler as a special case? (Like for a range-based for? I'm not sure if this makes sense.)

Comment: @n.caillou, The constructor does not take a `const T*` as input. The compiler processes the tokens at compile time and generates code to construct an object of type `std::initializer_list<T>` of the right size.

Comment: I guess this sort of answers the question—compilers treat it as a special case—but (and this is clearly implementation-dependent) at least for GCC this involves a private constructor `initializer_list(T* arr, size_t len)`. Also `std::initializer_list` seems copyable, but doing so does not copy the array. Anyway, given than an underlying array exists, its lifetime must be managed somehow.

Comment: @n.caillou, for better or worse, the standard does not dictate how an implementation chooses to construct an `intializer_list` given a list of tokens enclosed in `{}`. The standard does dictate that *Copying an `initializer list` does not copy the underlying elements.* See https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/support.initlist#2.